# deserializeUser for both user and adminstrator

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passportjs for my expressjs application:

I have both admin and user functionalities built in the same project.

I have successfully implemented authentication for user, now I am trying for admin.

I am stuck on how on the session serialize & deserialize :

```
    //use to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    //use to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
       models.User.find(id)
           .success(function(user){
              done(null, user);
           }).error(function(err){
               done(new Error('User ' + id + ' does not exists'));
           });
    });
```

How can I create another serialize & deserialize for admin?

Answer (score 2):

With passport.js you should ONLY define a single `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` function -- there is no need for separate ones for each type of user.

Instead, you should model your User model such that there is a permissions flag somewhere, like User.is_admin or something -- this is how you should distinguish between user types. If you do things this way, you can continue using the same serialization stuff for passport.

On a slightly unrelated note, if you're looking for a simpler way to do auth stuff, you might want to check out [express-stormpath](https://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/) -- I'm the author of it, so I'm quite biased, but it provides a simpler form of user integration as well as permissions / groups.